# UISegmentControl underline not on top in some cases

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to create a segment control with an underline for the selected segment.  I've found a few code snippets to do this but they seem to exhibit the same behavior where the underline is beneath the UISegment of the UISegment Control.  In this particular case, I'm using a UITableView custom cell with a UISegmentControl that has constraints to the top, left, bottom and right corners of the cell.  Only the 2nd segment shows up properly.  Here is what the debug view hierarchy looks like:

[image: First segment - Underline in the wrong spot]

[image: Second segment - Underline in the right position]

[image: Third segment - Underline in the wrong spot again]

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
extension UISegmentedControl{
    func removeBorder(){
        let backgroundImage = UIImage.getColoredRectImageWith(color: UIColor.white.cgColor, andSize: self.bounds.size)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .highlighted, barMetrics: .default)

        let deviderImage = UIImage.getColoredRectImageWith(color: UIColor.white.cgColor, andSize: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        self.setDividerImage(deviderImage, forLeftSegmentState: .selected, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 129/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)], for: .selected)
    }

    func addUnderlineForSelectedSegment(){
        removeBorder()
        let underlineWidth: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfSegments)
        let underlineHeight: CGFloat = 2.0
        let underlineXPosition = CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex * Int(underlineWidth))
        let underLineYPosition = self.bounds.size.height - 5.0
        let underlineFrame = CGRect(x: underlineXPosition, y: underLineYPosition, width: underlineWidth, height: underlineHeight)
        let underline = UIView(frame: underlineFrame)
        underline.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 129/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)
        underline.tag = 1
        self.addSubview(underline)
    }

    func changeUnderlinePosition(){
        guard let underline = self.viewWithTag(1) else {return}
        let underlineFinalXPosition = (self.bounds.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            underline.frame.origin.x = underlineFinalXPosition
        })
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels a bit hacky but I changed the following line:

```
self.addSubview(underline)
```

To the following:

```
for each in self.subviews {
    each.addSubview(underline)
```

Now, it works properly.  Even in the debug view hierarchy, I only see one underline UIView.  Strange.

Still interested in any other answers that might be a better solution.